# Please help with touchpad sensitivity and palm detection kernel 4.13

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I've searched for solutions, editing xinput and such but nothing works. I can scroll with my whole palm on the touchpad which drives me insane when I need to type something.

```
$ uname -r
4.13.0-36-generic

$ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (271): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (272):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (273):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (274):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (294):  1659, 5337, 1531, 4401
    Synaptics Finger (295): 50, 50, 200
    Synaptics Tap Time (296):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (297):   238
    Synaptics Tap Durations (298):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (299):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (300):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (301):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (302):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (303): -108, -108
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (304): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (305):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (306): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.036880, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (307):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (308):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (309):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (310): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (311):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (312): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (313):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (314): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (315):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (316): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (317):    5, 5
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (318): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (319):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (320): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (321):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (322):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (323):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (324):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (325): 53, 36
    Synaptics Area (326):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (327):  3498, 0, 4033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (328): 20, 20
    Device Product ID (264):    2, 7
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event7"
```

`Synaptics Finger: 50, 50, 200` works for me. However, my palm can easily mess with my typing even with `Synaptics Palm Detection` on and different `Synaptics Palm Dimensions` values
Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I like `Touchpad Indicator` GNOME Shell extension.

Find it at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/

Comment: This answer is short enough to qualify as a comment....